# When is a quantum algorithm considered to have a significantly superior performance over another quantum algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, optimization, experimental-realization

Suppose we have two heuristic quantum algorithms $A$ and $B$ that attempt to solve a certain class of optimization problems. Let's suppose that the benchmarking metric is Time To Solution (TTS), which is the expected total computation time required to find an optimal solution for a particular problem instance with 99% confidence. Smaller TTS indicates that an algorithm, on average, can find a solution to a problem in a shorter time period.

As an example, suppose for an $n$-variable optimization problem $A$ has TTS = 10 and $B$ has TTS = 100, then $A$ has 10x better performance.

We may assume that both $A$ and $B$ have the exponential scaling in TTS w.r.t. $n$, and from the benchmarking point of view, **we are only interested in TTS** (although it might be that one of the algorithms requires more quantum resources (gates and qubits) than the other).

My question is: what is the smallest order of magnitude that would be considered a significant improvement in TTS over a range of $n$? Or in other words, is it 10x, 100x, 1000x? Or maybe 2x is already a good result?

Here, I framed the question from the optimization point of view. But it doesn't have to be optimization. We could also consider that the classes of problems are search problems, state preparation, quantum tomography etc.

Edit:
I see someone voted that this question is opinion based. This might be partially true. However, before you conclude that it is entirely opinion based, please consider that there are quantum communities which have established soft cut-off thresholds for certain metrics. So, what could be a matter of opinion for you, could be a concrete number for another person who deals with quantum benchmarking.

Comment: To close voters and OP: I don't think the answer would be opinion-based. AFAIK, the answer should be something along the lines of "There's no real consensus on this because no one has...". The way I understand the question, it asks for a reference in which this matter is dealt with, in which case it should not be closed. If however the goal of the question is to solve the problem (that is, give a number without any reference to support it because of "natural reasons"), then the answer would most likely be opinion-based and the question should indeed be closed IMO.